# changes the value of pickerview according to another pickerview's value selection

Tags: xcode

I have two picker view p1 and p2 and in p1 data comes after parsing and the value of p2 is depends on the value selected in p1 so the value of p2 will be changes every time when we select the different different values in p1 and the value comes in p2 is also comes after parsing. So for that I need the name and id of the value selected in the p1 and I got the name as I will receive the name written in text box but the problem is how to fetch the id according to the name.

Comment: can i use "where" keyword like we do in database.
arr=[[dict objectforkey:@"id"]where];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `titleForRow` for `p2` should (a) identify what row is selected in `p1`; (b) use that to identify what string to return for the title, using `row` parameter within `p2`:

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if (pickerView == self.p1) {
        // do whatever you're doing for p1
    } else if (pickerView == self.p2) {
        NSInteger p1Row = [self.p1 selectedRowInComponent:0];

        // now lookup identifier in `p1` associated with row `p1Row`

        // now that you have the identifier for `p1`, now look up the text strings
        // for `p2` on the basis of (a) that identifier; and (b) the `row` number
        // passed to this method

        return ...; // now return the title
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Obviously, when you change your selection in `p1`, you can then reload `p2`. The following does a quick fade transition, to make the transition less jarring:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if (pickerView == self.p1) {
        [UIView transitionWithView:self.p2 duration:0.25 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
            [self.p2 reloadAllComponents];
            [self.p2 selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:NO];
        } completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the specific code details will vary based upon the model backing your picker views, but hopefully this illustrates the basic idea.